# How to extract certain data from HTML using RegEx?

Tags: html, regex, powershell, tags

I've got the following code:

```
<tr class="even">
            <td>
                Title1
            </td>
            <td>
                Name1
            </td>
            <td>
                Email1
            </td>
            <td>
                Postcode1
            </td>
```

I want to use RegEx in to output the data between the tags like so:

Title1
Name1
Email1
Postcode1
Title2
Name2
Email2
Postcode2
...

Comment: [Dare I say it?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/102937)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use a regex to parse html, use an HTML parser instead.

Anyway, if you really want a regex you can use this one:

```
>\s+<|>\s*(.*?)\s*<
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/dP9fA7/2)**

[image]
Match information:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [51-57] `Title1`
MATCH 2
1.  [109-114]   `Name1`
MATCH 3
1.  [166-172]   `Email1`
MATCH 4
1.  [224-233]   `Postcode1`
```

Answer (score 1):

This should get rid of everything between the tags, and output the rest space separated:

```
$text = 
@'
<tr class="even">
            <td>
                Title1
            </td>
            <td>
                Name1
            </td>
            <td>
                Email1
            </td>
            <td>
                Postcode1
            </td>
'@

$text -split '\s*<.+?>\s*' -match '\S' -as [string]

Title1 Name1 Email1 Postcode1
```

Answer (score 0):

[Don't use a regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) HTML isn't a regular language, so it can't be properly parsed with a regex. It will succeed most of the time, but other times will fail. Spectacularly.

Use the Internet Explorer COM object to read your HTML from a file:

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.visible = $false
$ie.navigate("F:\BuildOutput\rt.html")
$document = $ie.Document
# This will return all the tables
$document.getElementsByTagName('table')

# This will return a table with a specific ID
$document.getElementById('employees')
```

[Here's the MSDN reference for the document class.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535862.aspx)